# Execute SQL file from Spring JDBC Template

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to write a bit of code that reads a SQL file (multiple `CREATE TABLE` statements separated by `;`) and executes all the statements.

In pure JDBC, I could write:

```
String sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE A (...); CREATE TABLE B (...);"
java.sql.Connection connection = ...;
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate(sqlQuery);
statement.close();
```

and both (all) the statements got executed. When I tried to do the same in spring JdbcTemplate, only the first statement is executed though!

```
String sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE A (...); CREATE TABLE B (...);"
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
jdbcTemplate.execute(sqlQuery);
```

Is there a way to execute multiple statements? While googling I found only solutions like "split the sqlQuery by `;` manually" which of course is useless (it'd require much more parsing).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Maybe Spring's [ScriptUtils](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.html) will be useful in your case. Especially `executeSqlScript` methods.

Note that `DEFAULT_STATEMENT_SEPARATOR` has a default value of `';'` (see [Constant Field Values](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/constant-values.html))

Comment: it seems to work. Does remove comments though (which SQLite can keep as description for columns), but that does not worry me now that much.

Comment: Are there any ways to get number of rows changed using this executeSqlScript() method?

Comment: executeSqlScript are now deprecated. Any alternative?

Comment: @Daniele usually deprecated methods have a hint on what to use instead in their JavaDoc. However, I don't see any deprecation info even on the latest [ScriptUtils](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/5.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.html). Are you looking at a different class?

Comment: @DarioSeidl yes true. The deprecation started with spring Spring 4.0.3  in favor of using springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator

Comment: @Daniele may be referring to the indeed deprecated [executeSQLScript](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/jdbc/JdbcTestUtils.html#executeSqlScript-org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate-org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource-boolean-) methods provided by JdbcTestUtils, not the ScriptUtils.executeSQLScript() that (along with ResourceDatabasePopulator) is suggested as its replacement.

Answer (score 28):

I've solved the issue this way:

```
public void createDefaultDB(DataSource dataSource) {
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("CreateDefaultDB.sql");
    ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(resource);
    databasePopulator.execute(dataSource);
}
```

You can inject `DataSource` as usual:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
//...
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

Answer (score 11):

try it

```
public void executeSqlScript(Connection connection,StringBuffer sql)throws SQLException{
         try {
             connection.setAutoCommit(false);//disable auto commit
             ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(connection, new ByteArrayResource(sql.toString().getBytes()));
             connection.commit();//commit manually 
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            connection.rollback();
        }finally{
            connection.close();
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also achive through SQLExec. Below code is working for me.

import java.io.File;

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.Project;
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.executeSql("");
    }

    private void executeSql(String sqlFilePath) {
        final class SqlExecuter extends SQLExec {
            public SqlExecuter() {
                Project project = new Project();
                project.init();
                setProject(project);
                setTaskType("sql");
                setTaskName("sql");
            }
        }

        SqlExecuter executer = new SqlExecuter();
        executer.setSrc(new File("test1.sql"));
        executer.setDriver("org.postgresql.Driver");
        executer.setPassword("postgres");
        executer.setUserid("postgres");
        executer.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test");
        executer.execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar option for my project's case then I did stumble upon the following https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ResourceDatabasePopulator.html

The provided Stackoverflow example is really neat and simple, if you want the Spring to handle the boilerplate sql handling on your behalf https://stackoverflow.com/a/23036217/1958683