# Spring and MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, spring, stored-procedures, spring-jdbc

I have a stored procedure that works fine in the MySql workbench but when it is run by Spring, using the ResourceDatabasePopulator, it fails with a syntax error.
Reading around there are similar issues where the delimiter should be set in the script, I have followed these but the same error persists.

This is the SP

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE userAttributesOrder()
READS SQL DATA
    BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE attCount INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE cod VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL;
        DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT CODE FROM PA_ATTR_TYPE ORDER BY NAME ASC;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
        SET i = 0;    
        OPEN curs;
            read_loop: LOOP
                FETCH curs INTO cod;
                IF done THEN
                    LEAVE read_loop;
                END IF;
                INSERT INTO LAYOUT(ELEMENT_TYPE, ELEMENT_CODE, LAYOUT_ORDER) VALUES ('PA_ATTRIB', cod, i);
                SET i = i + 1;
            END LOOP;
        CLOSE curs;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And this is the exception

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #4 of resource class path resource [database/updates/23-update.sql]: DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE user
AttributesOrder() READS SQL DATA BEGIN DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corre
sponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE userAttributesOrder() READS SQL DATA BEGIN DECLARE' at line 1
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:472) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
```

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?  It is just Spring which I find frustrating as using plain Java I would not have the issue.

**UPDATE Spring code included**
As requested here is the Spring code I have inherited that runs the scripts.

```
DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();

for (String script : orderedScripts) {
    databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource(script));
}

initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator);
initializer.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Comment: That script won't work with the `ResourceDatabasePopulator` as that expects that `;` is the delimiter and it uses that to determine the end of the line.

Comment: @M. Denium hello thanks for the reply. Yes I realise that is the issue but the question is how to fix it so it will run. You surely can't say that  stored procedures cannot be used with ResourceDatabasePopulator! Setting the DELIMITER makes no difference and setting the delimiter in Spring with databasePopulator.setSeparator("$$");  Causes all the other scripts to fail, which is expected.  Anyone know how I can fix this so I can run a stored procedure with ResourceDatabasePopulator?

Comment: You cannot. Also you aren't running a stored procedure you are defining it. As a work around you can try putting this in a separate `ResourceDatabasePopulator` or implement your own `DatabasePopulator` with the delimiter set, and use a default one for the other scripts.

Comment: yeah I define it and run it in the next line... but thanks. Nice to know that Spring once more restricts what I want to do. I'll create a temp table, form my data, then copy across. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

I use **;;** as my separator setting it with [ResourceDatabasePopulator.setSeperator()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ResourceDatabasePopulator.html#setSeparator-java.lang.String-)

This doesn't seem to break other stuff and runs in my DB IDE.  My DB IDE (dbVisualizer) sees 2 seperators and doesn't care.

Answer (score 0):

I had been facing this issue too and just now I found a solution. **Actually 3**! So you can choose any of them which suits your needs. But the key to it is the correctly formatted `String` which represents the DB scripts to create a SP.
I haven't figure out how to combine **dropping and creation of a SP** in one SQL script/String, but I'm happy with those solutions anyway.

> FYI:
>
> - No special annotation or setting on the class nor method level is needed
> - I'm using [Spring FW](https://spring.io/), which simplifies things, so don't need to do low level implementation of everything
> - After searching and trying various definitely working 'tips', the following resources helped me to arrive to those for sure **working** solutions:
>
>   - [Execute SQL file from Spring JDBC Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732314/execute-sql-file-from-spring-jdbc-template)
>   - similar question [Issue with executing procedure in spring boot schema.sql file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48125485/2234369) on stackoverflow
>   - but most useful was official [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html) on JavaSE & JDBC
>   - and other [Java/JDBC tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-a-stored-procedure-in-a-database-using-jdbc-api) where you can see the most important bit of formatting the sql Java `String`

## Solution 1: using `JdbcTemplate` and Java `String`

It is very important to have trailing spaces in your nicely formatted `String` **sql** script

```
        String sqlSP = "CREATE PROCEDURE test_stored_proc (IN pInstanceId varchar(255)) " +
                "BEGIN " +
                    "SELECT * FROM vw_subscriptions WHERE instanceId = pInstanceId; " +
                "END";

        jdbcTemplate.execute(sqlSP);
```

## Solution 2: using `ResourceDatabasePopulator` & `ClassPathResource` to load SQL script in a file

```
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("/data/create-sp_TEST_STORED_PROC.sql");
        jdbcTemplate.execute("DROP procedure IF EXISTS `test_stored_proc`;");

        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(resource);
        databasePopulator.setSeparator(ScriptUtils.EOF_STATEMENT_SEPARATOR);
        databasePopulator.execute(testSetupDataSource);
```

## Solution 3: using `ScriptUtils` & `ClassPathResource` to load SQL script in a file

```
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("/data/create-sp_TEST_STORED_PROC.sql");
        jdbcTemplate.execute("DROP procedure IF EXISTS `test_stored_proc`;");

        ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(Objects.requireNonNull(testSetupDataSource).getConnection(), new EncodedResource(resource),
                false, false,
                ScriptUtils.DEFAULT_COMMENT_PREFIX, ScriptUtils.EOF_STATEMENT_SEPARATOR,
                ScriptUtils.DEFAULT_BLOCK_COMMENT_START_DELIMITER, ScriptUtils.DEFAULT_BLOCK_COMMENT_END_DELIMITER);
```

## Content of the `create-sp_TEST_STORED_PROC.sql` script

For solution #1 and #2 the same rule as for the 1st solution applies:

- The formatting and presence of *whitespace* characters is important especially an extra trailing space at the end of each line.

So the below code is archived by my `vim` setup of representing whitespace characters

```
CREATE·PROCEDURE·test_stored_proc·(IN·pInstanceId·varchar(255))~¬
BEGIN~¬
–→SELECT·*·FROM·vw_subscriptions·WHERE·instanceId·=·pInstanceId;~¬
END;~¬
```

I believe it is internally represented as one line piece of string:
`CREATE PROCEDURE test_stored_proc (IN pInstanceId varchar(255)) BEGIN SELECT * FROM vw_subscriptions WHERE instanceId = pInstanceId; END`

Almost full source-code can be found at my [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/delphym/5d339d00a655cc6cfe194cb97e4da511)