# How to execute postgres sql block from spring-boot

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-boot

I have to execute a block of sql script (typically a function) from spring boot application. I can't keep this function inside my postgres database as i want to maintain at application level. I tried to use `schema.sql` (from resources folder) and this looks like executing during server startup only.

However i want to call this *plsql* block everytime when needed through JPA or JDBCTemplate.

Any alternative other than `schema.sql` which can execute on-demand?

Comment: So why cant you just use JPA or JdbcTemplate then?

Comment: Problem is that I need to have this block of plsql in one of the sql file under resources folder and I should to call this sql file from JPA.

Comment: So just read the file into a string and execute it with JdbcTemplate. You seem to be overthinking things, or have some misconception about what spring-boot is.

Comment: just grab the JDBC connection from your JPA provider and write some JDBC to execute your schema.sql

Answer (score 1):

In unit tests there is [@Sql](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/Sql.html) annotation, that you can use to execute a script:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Sql("/reset_sequences.sql")
public class ModuleTemplateRepositoryTests { ... }
```

For launching custom sql script from spring application we were using [ScriptUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.html) (stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30732486/878241))

```
@Value("classpath:reset_sequences.sql")
Resource script;

@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

...
ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(
    jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection(), script);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have your function stored in the database you can look at this example [here](https://dzone.com/articles/calling-stored-procedures-from-spring-data-jpa).

Comment: Sorry, my function isn't stored in database. I should to execute the block of plsql without storing in database.