# Spring Hibernate MySQL initialization

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to figure out Spring Hibernate - MySQL relationship. My purpose is, when I start the program, it execute the `import.sql` file within the classpath. I want to do that without destroy existing tables. I found some documentation about execute sql file on startup.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

The official spring doc says;

> In addition, a file named import.sql in the root of the classpath will be executed on startup.

But, Spring destroy my tables and than execute import.sql file. Is there a way to execute .sql file without lost existing data?

In the below question, he almost wanted the same thing like me.

[How to import initial data to database with Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673802/how-to-import-initial-data-to-database-with-hibernate)

But;

> This will also work only if hbm2ddl.auto is set to create or create-drop.

I serached a lot but couldn't find a way. Long stroy short, how can I run .sql statement on startup without destroying database?

Comment: Read a little further... [Section about JDBC](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-intialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc) don't use Hibernate or JPA to initialize the database just use JDBC. Add a `data.sql` instead.

Comment: You could put the population of data in a application-scoped, non-lazy initialized bean (and run native sql queries from there)..

Comment: AFAIK, when configuring Hibernate, you can ask it to recreate the database schema on each and every start with the property `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>`. Be sure to set it at at most `validate`.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I read the section, and made the changes but it didn't execute the data.sql file. Here is the changes that I made;

`application.properties`

spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.data= classpath: data.sql
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto =

and my `data.sql` file in the src/main/resources folder like `application.properties` file.

Comment: You don't need to change anything, only add a `data.sql` everything else can remain as is. The file will be executed by default. Also please don't add  code as comments improve your question with it.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I undo the changes but still no execution. Based on this tutorial [link](http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-remember-me-example-with-hibernate/) the place for data.sql is src/main/resources folder isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can finally find the answers for my own question. I used java-based configuration on my project. Most of the examples on the internet related to spring use xml-based configuration, and it is difficult to me find the answers for my questions.

Luckyly I saw this question;

[How to execute SQL insert queries to populate database during application start/load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23029722/how-to-execute-sql-insert-queries-to-populate-database-during-application-start)

and the answer is

> DataSourceInitializer

It works like a charm!

Here is the code piece of running SQL statements on startup without destroy existing database.

```
@Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer() {
    ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("/data.sql"));

    DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource());
    dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
    return dataSourceInitializer;
}
```